# Can a Python script spawn a new process upon its own death?

Tags: python

Pretty much what the headline says. I want my Python script to exit and somehow schedule from within that script a new script for immediately *after* the first has finished.

Sounds simple enough but I can't seem to find a way -- let alone a clean way -- of doing that.

Comment: `os.system()` ?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for some kind of process management like `supervisord`.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to execute functions right before the interpreter exists with the 'atexit' module. You are even able to pass args and kwargs to the function.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

```py
import atexit
import os


def spawn_new():
    os.system("python3 -c 'print(\"Hello!\")'")


print("Main intepreter.")
atexit.register(spawn_new)
```